# How to accumulate for previous 7 days value in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery SQL, how can I accumulate values for some period?

I have a table like this.
And I want to get sum of previous 7 days value for each row.

Please let me know a query for this.

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-10 | 3 |
| 2021-05-11 | 1 |
| 2021-05-14 | 2 |
| 2021-05-15 | 0 |
| 2021-05-16 | 3 |
| 2021-05-17 | 1 |
| 2021-05-18 | 1 |
| 2021-05-20 | 1 |
| 2021-05-23 | 1 |
| 2021-05-28 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

Expected

| Date | Value | acc_7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-10 | 3 | 3 (Sum of 05-04 ~ 05-10) |
| 2021-05-11 | 1 | 4 (Sum of 05-05 ~ 05-11) |
| 2021-05-14 | 2 | 6 (Sum of 05-08 ~ 05-14) |
| 2021-05-15 | 0 | 6 (Sum of 05-09 ~ 05-15) |
| 2021-05-16 | 3 | 9 (Sum of 05-10 ~ 05-16) |
| 2021-05-17 | 1 | 7 (Sum of 05-11 ~ 05-17) |
| 2021-05-18 | 1 | 7 (Sum of 05-12 ~ 05-18) |
| 2021-05-20 | 1 | 8 (Sum of 05-14 ~ 05-20) |
| 2021-05-23 | 1 | 4 (Sum of 05-17 ~ 05-23) |
| 2021-05-28 | 1 | 2 (Sum of 05-22 ~ 05-28) |
| ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `range` window frame, but you need to convert the date to a number of days.

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (order by unix_date(date)
                        range between 6 preceding and current row
                       ) as value_7
from t;
```